# Pandas: split a row to two or more rows when applying a row-wise function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9],[4,9],[[1,2],[3,4]]], columns=['A', 'B'])
df

    A   B
0   4   9
1   4   9
2   [1, 2]  [3, 4]
```

However I would like to transform it to a table like this:

```
    A   B
0   4   9
1   4   9
2   1   2
3   3   4
```

Is there a way to apply a row wise function (using `df.apply(function,axis=1,...)` or some other function in pandas) to do that?

Comment: are there always just two items in the list? i.e. never something like [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 3):

Use lis comprehension with flatten values by `chain`:

```
from  itertools import chain

out = list(chain.from_iterable(item if isinstance(item[0],list) 
             else [item] for item in df[['A','B']].values))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['A','B'])
```

Or loop alternative:

```
out = []
for x in df[['A','B']].values:
    if isinstance(x[0], list):
        for y in x:
            out.append(y)
    else:
        out.append(x)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['A','B'])
print (df1)
   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  1  2
3  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension with `concat`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9],[4,9],[[1,2],[3,4]],], columns=['A', 'B'])

print (pd.concat([df.loc[:1], *[pd.DataFrame(list(i),columns=df.columns) for i in df.loc[2:].to_numpy()]],
                 ignore_index=True))
   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  1  2
3  3  4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
#main piece - the rest is actually 'fixing' the multiindex piece to fit your purpose:
df=df.stack().explode().to_frame()

df["id"]=df.groupby(level=[0,1]).cumcount()

df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(df.index.get_level_values(0)+df['id'], df.index.get_level_values(1)))

df=df.drop(columns="id").unstack()

df.columns=map(lambda x: x[1], df.columns)
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> df

   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  1  3
3  2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html), [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) and [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
types = df.applymap(type).eq(list)
arr = df.where(types).apply(pd.Series.explode).dropna().T.to_numpy()
df.mask(types).dropna().append(pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=df.columns), ignore_index=True)

   A  B
0  4  9
1  4  9
2  1  2
3  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using simple for and if loops:

```
 alist = df['A'].tolist()
 blist = df['B'].tolist()

 alist1=[]
 blist1=[]
 for k,r in zip(alist,blist):
   if isinstance(k,list):
     alist1.append(k[0])
     blist1.append(k[1])
   if isinstance(r,list):
     alist1.append(r[0])
     blist1.append(r[1])
   else:
     alist1.append(k)
     blist1.append(r)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': alist1, 'b': blist1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution to all others proposed so far using [DataFrame.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt), [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [DataFrame.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9],[4,9],[[1,2],[3,4]]], columns=['A', 'B'])
# Create index column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

tmp = df.melt(id_vars='index', var_name='columns').explode('value')

# Define indexes
idx = sum([list(range(len(tmp)//tmp['columns'].nunique())) for _ in range(tmp['columns'].nunique())], [])
tmp['index'] = idx

result_df = tmp.pivot(index='index', columns='columns', values='value')

result_df
columns  A  B
index        
0        4  9
1        4  9
2        1  3
3        2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem in the question, it is not certain the list items in the same row always has same length. 
If that presumption is satisfied, then following answer works for it:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode) 


    A   B
0   4   9
1   4   9
2   1   3
2   2   4
```